# text to list to tkinter problem with the list range

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, tkinter

am trying to use data from a text file and put it in a list and the generate labels in tkinter from the list that i get it from a text
when i run the code i become this error i know that the problem is because i dont have enough value from the Original text file for example some time i have 30 or 20 item in my text file but i need to have 36 lebel

```
import os
import subprocess
import fileinput
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import sys
import tkinter as tk


# Search an id and change it with a name and port
 master = Tk()
 master.geometry("300x300")




def change():
    SN = e1.get()
    NA = e2.get()

     with fileinput.FileInput("read.txt", inplace=True, backup='.bak') as 
file:
        for line in file:
            print(line.replace(str(SN), str(NA)), end='')

def creatswitch():
    BS = e3.get()
    with open("read.txt",'r+') as f:
        array = []
        te = str(BS)
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith(te):
                array.append(line.split("#")[0])


                for line in f:  # Continue iterating f for additional 
lines to keep
                if not line.rstrip():
                    break  # We hit an empty line, return to looking for 
switch
                    array.append(line.split("#")[0])




    Switch = tkinter.Tk()
    w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[1][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)

w.grid(row=0, column=1)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[3][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=2)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[5][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=3)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[7][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=4)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[9][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=5)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[11][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=6)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[13][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=7)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[15][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=8)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[17][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=9)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[19][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=10)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[21][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=11)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[23][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=12)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[25][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=13)
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[27][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
w.config(height=3, width=30)
w.grid(row=0, column=14)
   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[29][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=0, column=15)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[31][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=0, column=16)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[33][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=0, column=17)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[35][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=0, column=18)
   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[2][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=1)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[4][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=2)

    w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[4][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=3)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[8][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=4)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[10][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=5)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[12][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=6)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[14][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=7)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[16][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=8)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[18][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
    w.grid(row=1, column=9)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[20][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=10)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[22][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=11)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[24][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=12)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[26][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=13)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[28][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=14)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[30][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=15)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[32][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=16)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[34][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=17)

   w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[36][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
   w.config(height=3, width=30)
   w.grid(row=1, column=18)





    # bb = Button(Switch, text=str(sa), command=addtolist, height=5, 
  width=10)
    # bb.pack(side=LEFT)

   Switch.mainloop()


















 Label(master, text="Find").grid(row=0)
 Label(master, text="Replace").grid(row=1)
 Label(master, text="Switch").grid(row=2)
 e1 = Entry(master)
 e2 = Entry(master)
 e3 = Entry(master)

 e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
 e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
 e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

 Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=5, column=0, 
 sticky=W, pady=5)
 Button(master, text='Replace', command=change).grid(row=5, column=1, 
 sticky=W, pady=5)

 Button(master, text='Build ', command=creatswitch).grid(row=5, column=2, 
 sticky=W, pady=5)











 mainloop()


enter code hereFile "G:/infiband/infiband.py", line 
117, in creatswitch
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[33][7::]), bg="blue", 
fg="white")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please include it in your question.

Comment: enter code hereFile "G:/infiband/infiband.py", line 117, in creatswitch
w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[33][7::]), bg="blue", fg="white")
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include that information. It's very hard to read code in a comment.

Comment: am sorry for that am getting the following error  : Index Error: list index out of range

Comment: Basel.... the info in your comment post them as edit in your question you made. Its relevant information there and not in comments! End of triage review > requires editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have 36 labels but your data have only 20 values then it 
will be the simplest way to do:

Create a list with 36 elements. Fill the list with your 20 elements and 
complete the rest with some random value let's say with a string = "None"

```
#like your data from file would be
file_data = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] #this list is not filled with 20 elem. for simplification
length_of_data = len(file_data)
array = []
for i in range(36):
    if i <= length_of_data:
        array[i] = file_data[i]
    else:
        array[i] = "None"
```

So now your array is 36 elements long. 
array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "None", "None", "None", ...]

Why do you hard code your labels? A better way is to 
create your labels in a loop maybe you would realize that 
you don't need 36 labels.
If your data is 20 elements long then create just 20 labels.

```
list_of_labels = [] #for later needs
for i in range(len(array)):
    w = Label(Switch, text=str(array[i]), 
                bg="blue", fg="white", height=3, width=30)
    w.grid(row=0, column=i)
    list_of_labels.append(w)
```

Now you have 36 labels coded in 6 rows instead of in 108 rows!

Btw a python list index starts with 0 and not with 1.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help i know that mine problem ist from the list but i could not explain it cus of English and am working on it :) i did code the lebels like this cus then i have a tow row one is up and the other is down one is for single numbers and the other for duppel numbers in the end i should have a switch interface where i read the ports number from the text file and added to the lebels as a switch port like its connected am reallz sorrz for mz bad langueg and once again thanx for zour help

Comment: and i know that python list index starts with 0 and not with python list index starts with 0 but i dont need the first index thats why i use 1

Comment: Your welcome. Wait your name was Basel Mutlak right? Why change it?

Comment: am just new nere and yesterday i just tried to make my profile